# IDX21323 error and sometime looping in the URL in azure b2c

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I  am getting the error IDX21323 OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocolValidatedIdToken.Paylocad.Nonce was not null.

https://testing.demo.com/message=IDX21323:%20RequireNonce%20is%20'[PII%20is%20hidden]'.%20OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce%20was%20null,%20OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce%20was%20not%20null.%20The%20nonce%20cannot%20be%20validated.%20If%20you%20don't%20need%20to%20check%20the%20nonce,%20set%20OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce%20to%20'false'.%20Note%20if%20a%20'nonce'%20is%20found%20it%20will%20be%20evaluated.

I checked in other SO links and found this issue is related to redirect URI mismatch like if you have one URL in the code but different one in AZure.

[IDX21323 OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocolValidatedIdToken.Paylocad.Nonce was not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944071/idx21323-openidconnectprotocolvalidationcontext-nonce-was-null-openidconnectpro)

For me Redirect URI same for both i.e. in code and Azure. moreover I registered one application with two redirect URI (http://localhost:11111/ and https://testing.demo.com). so when I am running through local using localhost it's working fine but when I use https://testing.demo.com, I got IDX21323  error in my system, where as in different system its in a loop.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client ID}&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2fte%{tenant ID}%2foauth2%2fauthresp&response_type=id_token&response_mode=form_post&nonce={nonce 1}state=StateProperties%3deyJTSUQiOiJ4LW1zLWNwaW0tcmM6qswsdwdY2OTAtNzlk

The above URL remains same but only the nonce got changed everytime.

So is it because I have kept two redirect URI for the same application. Do I need to create two different application one for localhost (Redirect URI - http://localhost:11111) and another for Dev (Redirect URI - https://testing.demo.com)

Your expertise matters.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

I am doing this same thing, when my redirect URI is localhost, it works.
But when I make my redirect URI my server 
ex: ```httsp://<server>.<domain>.com/<instance>```
the authentication loop breaks and no authorization code is received.

Answer (score 0):

Its always recommended to use different application for development and production. Mainly from security and isolation point of view.

Your redirect_url seems to be wrong, its pointing to the tenant itself and hence in a loop. The redirect_uri below should be your app's reply url -  http://localhost:11111 or https://testing.demo.com,

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client ID}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:11111/&response_type=id_token&response_mode=form_post&nonce={nonce 1}state=StateProperties%3deyJTSUQiOiJ4LW1zLWNwaW0tcmM6qswsdwdY2OTAtNzlk

Comment: I tested the same in local. its working fine. I am not sure why for redirect URI "https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2fte%{tenant ID}%2foauth2%2fauthresp". Any Idea.