# How to solve Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException: IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'?

Tags: c#, azure, iis, owin, owin-middleware

I almost tried every solution so far for getting out of the problem of following exception.

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException: IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.
                              at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.ValidateNonce(OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext validationContext)
                              at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.ValidateAuthenticationResponse(OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext validationContext)
                              at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
```

But I am not able to get rid of the above exception.

**If I try second time, it works. But for very first time ( at very first attempt ), this does not work at all.**

I have Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect latest package installed into .NET application.
Mostly using default implementation of Owin middleware hooked up for IIS normal HTTP call.

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());                   

                app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                        ClientId = lClientId.ToString(),
                        Authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], lTenantId),
                        RedirectUri = "https://1001apvdp1012.forest7.dom/AHPOneFrontend/ExtAz/",

                        PostLogoutRedirectUri = string.Format(postLogoutRedirectUri, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.DnsSafeHost),

                        Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                        ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                        {
                            ValidateIssuer = true // This is a simplification
                        },
                        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                        {
                            AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                            SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated,
                            RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider
                        }
                    }
```

rest of other values are coming from configuration file.

I am attaching fiddler request flow to demonstrate about the request

[image]

[image]

[image]

The nonce cookie appended in the result response. Now If I try from this point own ward (again an attempt ), it will be successful. This time following URL would be posted to application server.

[image]

I really have no idea how to solve this.

I already saw the posts :

https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/07/receiving-error-idx21323-or-dx10311-requirenonce/
[IDX21323 OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocolValidatedIdToken.Paylocad.Nonce was not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944071/idx21323-openidconnectprotocolvalidationcontext-nonce-was-null-openidconnectpro)

.......

But these didnt solve my issue.