# ASP.net MVC Application having Nonce Problem in Subdirectory hosting in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, iis-7, owin

ASP.net MVC Application having Nonce Problem in Subdirectory hosting in IIS. I have a project in asp.net MVC and I wanted to add Azure Active Directory Login in this.

This is working well in localhost with Azure AD. But when hosted this application in Virtual Machine and when Tried to access this.
**It is showing error**: *"IDX21323: Require Nonce is '[PII is hidden]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated."*

I have already hosted many websites there in directory.
like

1. abc.mydominName.com/FirstProject
2. abc.mydominName.com/second Project
3. abc.mydominName.com/ThirdProject
4. abc.mydominName.com/FourthProject (I am publishing it here and accessing it with URL :"abc.mydominName.com/FourthProject" )

Answer (score 0):

There might be multiple reason for the error:

1. Firstly, please check if you have given the correct domain name  and verify.
2. Visual Studio IIS Express which hosts a website may by default  be using http. Check this and try using https:
3. Check if your  project URL's were different than the Redirect URI in Azure
   Check the URL in the AD App Registrations --> Settings --> Reply URL's. If url is https://localhost:44348/ ,then MVC project url should also be https://localhost:44348/
4. Check if Cookies involved in the authentication process, including the Nonce cookies, should have both of these attributes set:  SameSite=None and secure.
5. If you are having this problem only in chrome , you could try setting “cookies with same site must be secure ”  flag on chrome to be disabled.
   If nothing works , you can skip the error and handle it by using some thing like below in openid settings.

```js
   // skip IDX21323 exception
    if (context.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX21323"))
    {
       context.SkipToNextMiddleware();
    } else {
       context.HandleResponse();
       context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
    }
    return Task.FromResult(0);
```

**References:**

1. [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944071/idx21323-openidconnectprotocolvalidationcontext-nonce-was-null-openidconnectpro)
2. [Problem related to nonce](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/07/receiving-error-idx21323-or-dx10311-requirenonce/)