# How do I fix IDX21323 in ASP.NET webforms (Azure AD) application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, azure-active-directory

Every time when a user signs in  (via Azure Active Directory) for the first time everyday the system redirect the users to this:

> IDX21323: RequireNonce is 'System.Boolean'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated

I have tried the using these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944071/idx21323-openidconnectprotocolvalidationcontext-nonce-was-null-openidconnectpro) but it seems like these solutions are only for ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue couple of years back which I'd resolved by defining an empty Session_Start method in Global.aspx.cs file

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // place holder to solve endless loop issue
}
```

You can read about this workaround's more details at following github threads:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/542#issuecomment-74579842

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/70#issuecomment-346853448

Comment: i will test and get back to you

Comment: @prof_daily - Did the solution work for you?

Comment: unfortunately it did not work